# Concatenating three input fields into one model in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.year" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.month" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.date" />

{
expiration: expiry.year + expiry.month, expiry.date
}
```

How to concatenate this into one model?I have this inout fields exist in a multiple form.

Comment: I have to check friend...

Comment: Plese setup a plunker. You could use ng-change to update expiration when expiry is changed or do a watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a complete solution but you can work along these lines

```
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.year" ng-change="expiration = expiry.year + expiry.month, expiry.date" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.month" ng-change="expiration = expiry.year + expiry.month, expiry.date"  />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.date" ng-change="expiration = expiry.year + expiry.month, expiry.date"  />
```

it does not handle undefined etc case. better would be to write a function and do the concatenation in controller...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.year" ng-change="expirationUpdated()" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.month" ng-change="expirationUpdated()" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.date" ng-change="expirationUpdated()" />
```

do it in function

```
var expirationUpdated = function() { ///concate logic here}
```

Comment: Good idea on this part "ng-change" and call the function.I'll let the server handle my problem so that on edit/update no concatenation thing.makes code cleaner.@HarishR

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.year" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.month" />
<input type="text" ng-model="expiry.date" />

{{ expiration }}
```

You can setup a watch in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('expiry', function(newVal) {
    $scope.expiration = newVal.year + '-' + newVal.month + '-' + newVal.date
}, true);
```